# Triggering an animation at specified times

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, adobe

I'm in the process of learning the basics of Flash, and I just figured out how to animate a symbol/ instance through editing the symbol's frames once you double click on it.

Is there a way to trigger an animation? For example have the default animation of a person facing the screen being him bobbing up and down. But when the right arrow key is pressed, then `goto` an animation of him bobbing up and down facing the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an animation from frame 1 to 10, on frame 10 insert the code:

```
gotoAndPlay(1);
```

Create the second animation loop from frame 11 to 20, on frame 20 insert the code:

```
gotoAndPlay(11);
```

etc..

then add an event listener to the stage to listen to keyboard event:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyBoard);
function handleKeyBoard(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  switch( event.keyCode ) {
    case Keyboard.RIGHT :
      animation.gotoAndPlay(11);// you can use label names or frame index
      break;
    case Keyboard.LEFT :
      animation.gotoAndPlay(1);// return to original loop
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Quick question though: for the place where I would input the code, I would need to double click on the image, to edit the symbol. And then where would I insert the code? Would I need to click on the frame 10, and then put the code where?

Comment: Place it at the first frame of the timeline containing your animation. Note that you may need to change animation.gotoAndPlay to simply gotoAndPlay so that it targets the current scene instead of an object on stage

Answer (score 0):

What you mean `at specified times` may be the event trigger time.

So my advise is to **add an event listener** to what you want to trigger an animation when a specific event triggered.

For example, when the right arrow key is pressed, then goto an animation of him bobbing up and down facing the right side of the screen.

```
animation.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, 
    function onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        //When Right key is pressed
        if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
        {
            //animation.gotoAndPlay("bobbing up and down");
            //or do something else
        }
    });
```

Comment: Keyboard event needs to bind to Stage, not the target sprite

Comment: Thanks! This is similar to what mika said, (although the listener would be for the stage) so I gave you an upvote/ whatever they're called in SO.